# While loop if condition is not met

Tags: python

I want to break out of the loop if y or n is set. In my head this is the way to do it, but it seems to get stuck in the while loop even when 'str1' is set to both n and y.

I have also tried to do: `while str1 != "y" or str1 != "n":` without luck.

```
str1 = ""
while not str1 == "y" or not str1 == "n": 
    str1 = input('setting [y/n] => ')
    str1 = str1.lower()
```

Comment: `while str1 != "y" and str1 != "n":`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your condition `while str1 != "y" or str1 != "n"` is always `True`, if you enter `n` it'll be different of `y` and vice-versa.

You want to stop if both condition aren't met

```
while str1 != "y" and str1 != "n"
```

Or easier

```
while str1 not in "yn":
```

Comment: Of course.. No idea why I didn't think of that. I guess it's too late for me when I start getting errors on stuff like that! Thanks!